# Efficient printing of custom trading card design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

My son and I are designing a custom card game and I've got dozens of 63mm x 88mm "trading card"-size designs. Eventually, I'll want to professionally print them but for now am just temporarily printing them on my laserjet.

Is there an efficient way for me to print several per page? Right now, I just have one artboard with different layers but I can change this if needed. One standard sheet of paper could fit six of these cards, I'd just like to be more efficient.

Comment: Why can't you arrange 6 on a page? Or better yet if you have Adobe CC link the cards to a layout in InDesign. Sorry, I might be confused on what's challenging.

Comment: I'm not an illustrator expert, so I don't know if there's an easy way. I have a single art board so that only prints one card. Do I need to duplicate the art and just design six on a larger art board?

Comment: Yeah enlarge the artboard and put 6 on a single board. Or as I said, if you have Adobe Creative Cloud subscription then you can use InDesign. Setup a Master Page with 6 placeholders then link the cards. Can even automate a lot of it in InDesign. Those are the main methods that come to my mind, someone else might have another solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily print multiple cards in one sheet using just acrobat readers `"Print..."` dialog

If you have a multi-page pdf you can specify to print multiple pages per sheet
[image: Select option "multiple pages per sheet"]

The best way to get a multi-page pdf document would be to place your individual card designs into separate artboards. You can open the original ai-file directly in acrobat or save it as a pdf from illustrator.

If you want to print only one design, you might want to keep using only one artboard in illustrator and duplicate the pages inside acrobat before printing

Answer (score 0):

If you created your `document`:

[image]

and placed your design in the document:

[image]

Go to `File -> Document Setup`:

[image]

Click the button `Edit Artboards` and at the top right enter the specs to increase the size:

[image]

Enter in the new measurements for your intended size:

[image]

[image]

Click <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and the rulers will appear.  Make sure the guide is not locked by right clicking:

[image]

If the guide is unlocked you can select the guide and go to `transform` and move the guide in the exact position you need:

[image]

I do recommend placing your guides on a different layer then your designs and locking the layer and naming it guides

You could easily do this in InDesign but this was tagged for Illustrator.

[image]

If you want to add custom bleeds to the document then add it to a new layer and go back to the options and uncheck `Print`